# How do I get a specific element in array - MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

***Documents store in mongo db in following form***

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54fa059ce4b01b3e086c83e9"),
    "field1" : "value1",
    "field2" : "value2"
    "field3" : [ 
        {
            "abc123": ["somevalue", "somevalue"]
        },
        {
            "xyz345": ["somevalue", "somevalue"]
        }
    ]
}
```

What I want in output is whenever I pass ***abc123*** in pymongo query I need result in following form

```
{
     "abc123": ["somevalue", "somevalue"]
}
```

or

```
["somevalue", "somevalue"]
```

Please suggest a mongo query for it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
 {
$project: {
  field3: {
    "$filter": {
      "input": "$field3",
      "as": "f",
      "cond": {
        $ne: [
          "$$f.abc123",
          undefined
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
},
{
  $unwind: "$field3"
},
{
"$replaceRoot": {
  "newRoot": "$field3"
 }
}
])
```

Explained:
Use the mongo aggregation framework with below 3x stages:

1. project/filter only the needed array field3 if exist
2. unwind the field3 array
3. replace the root document with the content of field3

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Bs6QJXTLmQa)